# How to use Omake build system for a Visual studio 2010 project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc, makefile, omake

I have a project, which works fine in `VS-2010`. And runs fine.
But I want to create a `make-file` by using `Omake`. How to build the same in `Omake`.
I have gone through all the documentation of `Omake`, but it does not say how to make it.
My `VS-2010` project contains `.c, .cpp, .h, .rc` MFC and `many subdirectories` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to convert a project from VS to Omake: you have to write the 'OMakefile's by hand since the two build systems (MSBuild is behind VS) and concepts are somewhat different. Once the OMakefile's are working, you can always create a Visual Studio project of type "Makefile" that calls the omake utility behind the scene.

If the reason for change is that you want to make the projet multi-platform (well, I doubt so since you use MFC), you may consider [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/), a widely-used project generation tool. CMake can generate both Makefiles (GNU) and VS projects, depending on the platform, from a project description.